# Delphi IOS linker error library not found

Tags: ios, delphi, hyperlink

I'm trying to use a third party framework, that needs a library, in Delphi IOS. To get Delphi to link it in i've entered the following statement:

```
procedure StubProc1; cdecl; external 'AerServSDK.a' dependency 'libxml2.2';
```

When i build it i get the following error:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: library not found for -llibxml2.2
```

The library is in the usr\lib directory, and it doesn't matter whitch library i try. Apparently some searchpath needs to be updated, but where and how??

Comment: Are you sure you even need to include the dependency entry?

Comment: Incidentally, are you passing -ObjC to the linker flags? Attempting to link the AerServSDK (without "dependency") against the iOS 11.3 SDK results in a bunch of "dwarf" errors for me, using Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 (iOS 11 patches applied)

Comment: I am passing -ObjC, and yes i get the same errors.

Comment: Can you link it?

Comment: No, since I have those errors. I'm yet to look into why they happen

Comment: I think all the dwarf errors is because of the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is, to omit the "lib" part of the library name. So it's:

```
procedure StubProc1; cdecl; external 'AerServSDK.a' dependency 'xml2.2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the path to the library in the source path of the project (like you do with .pas file).

add theses 2 rows :

```
procedure StubProc1; cdecl; external 'AerServSDK.a';
procedure StubProc2; cdecl; external 'libxml2.2';
```

`AerServSDK.a` and `libxml2.2` (ie: the file `libxml2.2` without any extension) must be in your source path

Comment: I also tried copying the library to my project directory. Doesn't work

Comment: I edited the answer, can you try like this if it's work ?