# Delphi IOS linker error

Tags: ios, delphi

I'm trying to use a third party framework(AerServSDK), in Delphi IOS.

When i build it i get the following error:

```
ld: sectionForAddress(0x2AAA) address not in any section for architecture 
armv7
```

Does anybody know what that means?

Comment: Is this using the same approach as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781443/delphi-ios-linker-error-library-not-found ? Or have you made changes since then? Because that approach worked for me.

Comment: What approach do you mean?

Comment: Read your own answer in the post I linked. I even upvoted it

Comment: Okay, but i can't link it. I still get the same errors. You could link it?

Comment: I was able to compile and link with 10.2.3, Xcode 9.4.1, targeting iOS 11.4 SDK. This was using no linker flags, however. Using -ObjC resulted in a bunch of DWARF errors